# Reading number of endline

Tags: c

I created this code but it tells me that the number of \n is always 0.. \n is 10 in ASCII is that right or I'm wrong? there's a way to do it easier?

C Program from a file ,it takes the number of newline.
The Father creates 8 sons.
Every son take a part of the file(1/8)
The value of the son will return to the father 
When all sons returned, the father print the sums of all value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ourhdr.h>

#define taglia 1000

void figlio(int,int,int*,char*);


int main(int argc,char*argv[]){

    if(argc<1)
        return 0;
    int fd;
    if((fd=open(argv[1],O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        err_sys("Open failed");
    int sum=0,k;
    pid_t process[8];
    int p[8][2];

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        if((pipe(p[i])) < 0)
            err_sys("Pipe failed");
        if((process[i]=fork()) < 0)
            err_sys("Fork failed");
        else if(process[i]==0){
            figlio(i,fd,p[i],argv[1]);
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            if((wait(NULL)) < 0)
                err_sys("Wait failed");
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        if((read(p[i][0],&k,sizeof(int))) < 0)
                    err_sys("Read  failed");

                sum+=k;
    }

    printf("Somma di tutte le linee =  %d",sum);
}



void figlio(int i,int fd,int p[],char argv[]){

    int linee=0;
    int l;
    //if((open(p[0],O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        //err_sys("Open figlio failed");

    if((fd=open(argv,O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        err_sys("Open failed");

    if((lseek(fd,taglia*i*sizeof(int),SEEK_SET)) < 0)
        err_sys("lseek failed");

    for(int j=0;j<taglia/8;j++){
    if((read(fd,&l,sizeof(int))) < 0)
        err_sys("read this failed");

    if(l==10)
        linee++;

    }

    if((write(p[1],&linee,sizeof(int))) < 0)
        err_sys("Write failed");

}
```

Comment: You read 32-bit integer values from the pipe, not single-byte characters.

Comment: And please don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you want to compare something to a newline then use the actual newline `'\n'`.

Comment: In ASCII, integer value of '\n' is 10.   
But, how the input file is written ?  Do you read it in the same way as it is written ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading in chunks of `int` when I think you intend on reading single `char`.

For example, in this line:

```
/* int l = 0; */

if((read(fd,&l,sizeof(int))) < 0)
    err_sys("read this failed");
```

Should be this:

```
/* char l = 0; */

if((read(fd,&l,sizeof(char))) < 0)
    err_sys("read this failed");
```

If I had to guess, I'm thinking you're probably going to have to change this line to:

```
if((lseek(fd,taglia*i*sizeof(int),SEEK_SET)) < 0)
    err_sys("lseek failed");
```

Into:

```
if((lseek(fd,taglia*i*sizeof(char),SEEK_SET)) < 0)
    err_sys("lseek failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading 4 or 8 bytes at a time (depending on whether your program is compiled as 32-bit or 64-bit) and checking if the group of 4 or 8 bytes is 10. The only way that can happen is if 1 of the bytes is 10 (either the first or last, depending on the type of computer) and all the rest of the bytes are 0. 0 bytes are not valid in text files so presumably this never happens.

You should read a char at a time from the file instead of an int.